# Laravel 8: Redirect to Controller action not working

Tags: redirect, controller, laravel-8

I have trouble doing a redirect to a controller action in Laravel 8. I am trying to do it like this:

### api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\DownloadController;

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/testdownload', function () {
    return redirect()->action([DownloadController::class, 'testDownload']);
});
```

### DownloadController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Zip;

class DownloadController extends Controller
{
    public function testDownload() {
        return Zip::create("test.zip", ['/mnt/datenschleuse/euler/sec_transfer/clean/1GB_bereinigt.bin']);
    }
```

But instead of being redirected to the controller action I get this in the logs:

```
[2021-05-05 15:02:15] local.ERROR: Action App\Http\Controllers\DownloadController@testDownload not defined. {"userId":"2bd3195a-2f67-1033-8994-a53eb149a944","exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Action App\\Http\\Controllers\\DownloadController@testDownload not defined. at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:468)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.php(220): Illuminate\\Routing\\UrlGenerator->action()
#1 /var/www/html/routes/api.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Redirector->action()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(230): Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteFileRegistrar->{closure}()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(200): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runCallable()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(695): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle()
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(127): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(103): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handleRequest()
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(55): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter()
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handle()
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(44): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle()
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/Http/Middleware/EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php(33): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Laravel\\Sanctum\\Http\\Middleware\\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful->Laravel\\Sanctum\\Http\\Middleware\\{closure}()
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest()
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle()
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle()
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/Http/Middleware/EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php(26): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Laravel\\Sanctum\\Http\\Middleware\\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful->Laravel\\Sanctum\\Http\\Middleware\\{closure}()
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/Http/Middleware/EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php(34): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Laravel\\Sanctum\\Http\\Middleware\\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful->handle()
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(697): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#32 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(672): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(636): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#34 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(625): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#35 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#36 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#37 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#38 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#39 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle()
#40 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#41 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#42 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle()
#43 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#44 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#45 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#46 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#47 /var/www/html/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#48 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle()
#49 /var/www/html/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#50 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle()
#51 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#52 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#53 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#54 /var/www/html/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#55 /var/www/html/server.php(21): require_once('...')
#56 {main}
"}
```

I have other actions in my DownloadController which work fine (but I don't use redirects to access them). What is the reason the action is not defined? It's just there in the Controller and should work as expected like described in the Laravel docs (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#redirecting-controller-actions).

Answer (score 0):

That's because Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse expects a URL to redirect to.
If your action is not registered in your route list (artisan r:l) there's no URL to redirect to.

For example:

This would work

```
Route::get('test', ([DownloadController::class, 'testDownload']);

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/testdownload', function () {
    return redirect()->action([DownloadController::class, 'testDownload']);
});
```

Grüße nach Hessen :)